# Referencing a file via classpath in spring context

Tags: java, spring, ide

I'm trying to set `org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` spring bean, I have jdbc.properties in `src/main/config` .. when I put this file in `src/main/resources` and put `classpath:` in value my app deploys successfuly.

This works when jdbc.properties is located in `src/main/resources`

```
 <property name="location" value="classpath:jdbc.properties" />
```

However I'm required to put any configuration inside `src/main/config` , how do I point springs towards this location in the right way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a classpath issue, not a Spring issue.  Add src/main/config to your classpath and it will work.  In Eclipse, this means adding it to the project Build Path->Source.

Comment: +1 for two reasons: Totally a classpath issue.  Also, mentioning HOW to do it in an IDE.

Comment: I added ` <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/config" including="**/*.properties"/>` to my .classpath and its still not working

Comment: Did you restart Eclipse after doing that?  That's how it's done, although the including= part isn't required.

Answer (score 3):

The right answer to this is given by @[matt b](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4249/matt-b) ,

> "What I am referring to is the fact
>   that when you package the application,
>   the config files are not packaged in a
>   folder named src/main/config  in the
>   packaged file (jar/war/etc.).
>   Therefore your answer only works when
>   you run the application within the
>   source code, or when src/main/config 
>   is in the classpath (which it is not
>   by default). The correct prefix is to
>   use classpath: or another location."

In this question :

[Trying to setup externalizing properties in spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524161/trying-to-setup-externalizing-properties-in-spring/)

Comment: That does look like another version of hte same question

Answer (score 1):

If it is a maven project, you can add

```
<resources>            
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/config</directory>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
        </resource>
<resources>
```

to you `<build>` in your pom.xml

Comment: Try posting answer to new questions. This question was asked in 2010 and already has an accepted answer