# Newly Mavenized Project - Cannot Find Classpath

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have a static main that points to an application Context file.  Before the project was made a maven project, I kept "applicationContex.xml" in the "" (i.e. root) of Netbeans.  Now when I run my code I get the error shown.

Can someone tell me the right location for my application context file?

```
@Service
public class TestDriver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
```

Error:

```
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist


Directory of C:\NetBeansProjects\prj\trunk\src\main\java

8/15/2012  09:38 AM    <DIR>          .
8/15/2012  08:58 AM    <DIR>          ..
8/15/2012  09:38 AM               162 jcbc.properties
8/15/2012  09:38 AM               879 log4j.properties
8/15/2012  09:38 AM             1,691 applicationContext.xml
              3 File(s)          2,732 bytes
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the `maven` conventions keep the xml files under `src/main/resources`

From [SpringSource](http://blog.springsource.org/2011/01/17/green-beans-getting-started-with-maven-and-spring/)

```
src/main/java
```

Contains the Java source code for your project

```
src/main/resources
```

Contains any classpath-relative resources for your project (like, a Spring application context .xml file)

```
src/test/java
```

Contains the java source code for your test classes. This directory will not be included in the final build. All tests herein will be compiled and all tests will be run. If the tests fail, it aborts the build.

```
src/test/resources
```

This directory will not be included in the final Java build. This folder contains any classpath-relative resources for your test code (like, a Spring application context .xml file).

Comment: That's very helpful.  Do you know where I should put jdbc.properties?  I put it in the resources directory, but it doesn't see it there.

Comment: src/main/config seems to be the place for jdbc.properties. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525028/referencing-a-file-via-classpath-in-spring-context?lq=1

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the non-java files in:

```
C:\NetBeansProjects\prj\trunk\src\main\resources
```

Comment: This is recommended but not necessary.